# Скопировать файлы по маске из разных папок

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Есть более 300 папок 2021-01-01 , 2021-01-02 и т.д. В каждой из папок разные файлы, но с одинаковым названием, например нужно достать NAMEOF_22.txt
Как можно командой linux получить только эти файлы по маске NAMEOF и скопировать файлы из всех этих папок в одну папку, чтобы не копировать вручную?

Comment: например: `$ cp ????-??-??/nameof* куда-то/`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin таким образом вроде как только с 1 папки произойдет копирование? Или просто указать cp 2021-*/nameof* куда-то/ можно?

Comment: а вы проверьте.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin буду в офисе у компьютера через пару часов, спасибо большое.

Comment: `find . -name 'NAMEOF*.txt' -a -type f -exec cp {} /path/to/dst/ \;`

Comment: @PakUula вам тоже большое спасибо!)

Comment: @PakUula, цитирую вопрос ` В каждой из папок разные файлы, но с одинаковым названием ... и скопировать файлы из всех этих папок в одну папку` посему, думаю в результирующей папаке может оказаться один файл. А так вариант вполне себе ничего.

Comment: @Namerek да, я тоже обратил на это внимание, но конкретый запрос был *файлы по маске NAMEOF*. Вот как раз по этой "маске" и выполняется `find`.

Comment: @PakUula И все-же я бы не рискнул сваливать файлы из разных папок в одну предварительно не позаботившись об уникализации имени (за исключением случая если я сам писал скрипт который файлы по исходным папкам раскладывает и я на этом этапе уже позаботился об уникализации имени)

Answer (score 0):

`cp -i $(find ./ -name "*.txt") ./txt_files/` например....